# How do you add multiple notifications in objective-c Xcode 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I'm trying to create an application that fires off a notification every day. The problem is I would like the application to put a different notification each day. I've researched this quite a lot prior to asking for help. Thank you so much! Maybe this would be an array I don't know?

```
 NSDate *AlarmTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (notifyAlarm) {
    notifyAlarm.fireDate = AlarmTime;
    notifyAlarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifyAlarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    notifyAlarm.soundName = @"Soundy.wav";
    notifyAlarm.alertBody = @"Go Back and learn more random facts!";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm];
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this would be a server, not the app. This gives you 2 powerful advantages:

You can regulate remotely the notification the comes in without updating the app.
You can add code to see wether or not the application push notification was seen / reacted to.

Comment: Thanks, Michael...although, I'm not entirely sure what you mean? Could you please expand on this. Sorry...for my incompetence!

Comment: Don't apologize for your incompetence! We learn by asking questions :)

Check out this tutorial on setting up a server for custom pushes 

[Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: Michael, Thank you sir for the quick response. It is greatly appreciated! It's awesome for a community when developers can come. I always anxious ro learn! ;)